# Is there any way to report players in MW2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, cheats

This is terrible. Almost every lobby I join is hacked, especially on S&D and F4A. Yesterday they reset all my custom classes, setting a **smoke grenade** as my primary weapon.

Is there any way to report hackers in MW2 so they get banned, or at least get a warning?

I'm on a PlayStation 3 system, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, since the fall out between Infinity Ward and Activision and the release of Black Ops, support for MW2 is non-existent.  You can contact [Robert Bowling](http://twitter.com/#!/fourzerotwo) via twitter but it fall on deaf ears.

I have recently started playing MW2 again and noticed that every other lobby I joined has been modified in some way.

The best way to avoid hackers it just to back out of the lobby as soon as possible.  I have been lucky that they have not messed with any of my game settings...

You can also register a [complaint](http://np.us.playstation.com/complaint/pc/ComplaintForm.aspx) with Sony support about the users who were hosting hacked lobbies