# I joined a compromised server and now my account is messed up

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Okay, so I was playing a game and this guy used cheats. I hate playing a game with cheats so I left but now my name is no longer white: it is now yellow. When I go to the leaderboards during the game, it is huge. Also, when I go to my classes of guns, instead of it showing my primary guns, it shows this weird-looking grenade that looks like it was hand-drawn, and my secondary gun is a pistol. I am really annoyed by this; can anyone tell me how this might be fixed?

Comment: This question detailed the same problems you explained: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14742/is-there-any-way-to-report-players-in-mw2

Answer (score 1):

all the forums and [news](http://www.gamedaily.com/articles/news/ps3-hacking-renders-modern-warfare-2-unplayable/) suggest that there is nothing that can be done about the stats etc.

You could start a new profile and play in [closed lobbies](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2011-01-17-infinity-ward-blames-mw2-hacks-on-ps3), or just go to black ops, but this is indeed a very sad thing.

Update: 
Infinity Ward has released a new [patch](http://www.infinityward.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=260502) which claims to fix these problems.

> - Care Package, Emergency Airdrop, and Sentry Gun marker grenades sprint
>     speed normalized.
> - Fix for "infinite care package" exploit.
> - Sentry Guns: Improved placement detection, preventing cases of Sentry
>     Guns inside geometry.
> - Model 1887: Bling using Akimbo and FMJ combination now has same range and
>     damage as non-Bling Model 1887s.
> - Fixes to prevent various XP hacks (including the prevention of negative
>     XP)